# Selecting all users with minimum one order or more with mySQL

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, having-clause

```
SELECT users.id, COUNT(?) FROM orders
INNER JOIN users ON (orders.user_id = users.id)
WHERE ??
```

How can i output:

```
UserID: 123 has made 22 orders
UserID: 124 has made 2 orders
```

and so on?

I would like to only grab the users that has one or more orders, and exclude those with 0 orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT users.id, COUNT(*) FROM orders
INNER JOIN users ON (orders.user_id = users.id)
group by users.id
having count(*)>=1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT users.id, COUNT(*) FROM orders
INNER JOIN users ON (orders.user_id = users.id)
GROUP BY users.id
HAVING count(*) >= 1
```